# Big( O ) Notation: Can anyone verify?

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory, pseudocode

So I'm answering a question for one of my computing classes.  I developed an algorithm and then it asked me for the complexity of the algorithm.  I'm not very good at determining complexity for the moment, so can anyone verify?

The code follows:

```
if( A.type is not Comparable ): return False                   // Max runs = 1
current ← A.head                                               // Max runs = 1
printedFirst ← False                                           // Max runs = 1
while( current.hasNext ):                                      // Max runs = s-1
    if ( current.value < current.next.value ):                 // Max runs = s-1 
        if ( printedFirst ): print “, “                        // Max runs = s-1
        print “(“ + current.value + “, “ + current.next.value + “)” //runs = s-1
        printedFirst ← True                                    // Max runs = s-1
    current = current.next                                     // Max runs = s-1
```

So we have

```
3( 1 ) + 6(s - 1) = 3 + 6s - 6 = 6s - 3 = O( n )
```

Correct?

Comment: You aren't changing `i` inside the loop are you?  That would make it an infinite loop.

Comment: well, it would probably crash.. ;)

Comment: Haha..  does that still make it O( n )?  =)  I've updated the algorithm

Comment: I guess you could argue that Infinity is a constant, so its O(1), but you'd probably be on thin ice ... :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A single while loop, with only a single if inside... go for O(n).

Good luck with your classes.